# AWS - Data Migration Service

Tags: amazon-web-services

Trying to Migrate RDS mysql to Redshift, When connecting the AWS RedShift Database in Target Connection it Throws the Error:

**Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: IN/A, Application-Detailed-Message: N/A**

Please help to resolve...

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue by adding few ingress/egress rules weren't defined on the security groups which are attached to DMS and Redshift.

Check this link for further information: [AWS DMS endpoint connection to Redshift not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446270/aws-dms-endpoint-connection-to-redshift-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

In your DMS (Data Migration Service) configuration where you enter the Server Name value, avoid the Redshift cluster DNS Name or the Public IP address. Instead, try using the private IP of the Redshift Leader node. It worked for me after I changed to the private IP of leader node.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the private IP of redshift in the server name of the endpoint worked. I don't know why but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

AWS - Data Migration Service Endpoint Redshift error (Test failed)

The Leader private IP of redshift in the server name of the endpoint will work.