# DMS Serverless replication fails to connect to Redshift Serverless endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, replication, serverless, dms

I am trying to replicate data from an RDS MySQL instance to Redshift Serverless, using DMS Serverless.

Following AWS docs, I have set up the following:

[Prerequisites for AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_GettingStarted.Prerequisites.html#CHAP_GettingStarted.Prerequisites.VPC)

1. A Redshift Serverless instance, with subnets and security groups
2. An RDS MySQL instance, with subnets and security groups
3. A DMS Serverless replication, with subnets and security groups
4. IAM roles and policies
5. Endpoints in DMS for MySQL and Redshift Serverless, and a VPC endpoint for Redshift Serverless

All instances and endpoints are in the same VPC.

RDS MySQL is running. I can connect to it through a client and run queries.
*Note: I have successfully replicated data from the same RDS instance to S3, using a separate replication.*

Redshift Serverless is running. I can connect to it through Redshift query editor v2.

**Network Config**

1. The security group (DMS-SG) for DMS has an Outbound rule of `All traffic/All/All/0.0.0.0/0`
2. The security group (Red-SG) for Redshift has an Inbound rule of `Redshift/TCP/5439/id of DMS-SG`
3. The security group (Red-SG) has an Inbound rule of `MYSQL/Aurora/TCP/3306/id of DMS-SG` (MySQL and Redshift use the same SG)
4. Endpoints in DMS for RDS MySQL and Redshift Serverless
5. A VPC endpoint (interface type) for Redshift (Enhanced VPC routing is turned ON), as per AWS docs:

[Enhanced VPC Routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html#CHAP_Target.Redshift.EnhancedVPC)

[Configuring VPC endpoints as AWS DMS source and target endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_VPC_Endpoints.html)

- A DMS Subnet group, with at least 3 subnets in 3 different AZs, each
  with a pool of free IPs, required for Redshift Serverless processes.
  Can't find the docs for that, but I got errors telling me to do that
  when I created less than 3 subnets.
- A role named `dms-vpc-role` with the following permissions:
- Cloudwatch access:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AmazonDMSVPCManagementRole

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AmazonDMSRedshiftS3Role

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dms-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The bucket for Redshift is named `dms-*`

dms-s3-access

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::gs-xxx-xxx-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::dms-xx-xxxshift/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::gs-xxx-xxx-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::dms-xx-xxxshift"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And a trust policy as part of `dms-vpc-role`:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "dms.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

According to this SO post [aws-dms-endpoint-connection-to-redshift-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446270/aws-dms-endpoint-connection-to-redshift-not-working)

(and some AWS docs as well), I need 2 more roles:

`dms-cloudwatch-logs-role`
`dms-access-for-endpoint`

Not sure where to find the policy settings for these, or if they are covered by the policies I created above. I believe they are covered, but correct me if not.

My Redshift Serverless endpoint URL is `xx-workgroup.123456781234.ca-central-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com:5439/dev`.
As per AWS docs, this is the Server name to be specified in the DMS target endpoint definition.
Do I need to specify the `port/DBname` as part of the endpoint URL, when I am specifying a different DBname in the `Database Name` parameter of the endpoint config in DMS? Could this be conflicting?

Another thing which I can't figure out is where to specify this Trust policy, as required by this AWS doc:
[Target Redshift RSServerless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html#CHAP_Target.Redshift.RSServerless)

```
    "PolicyVersion": {
        "CreateDate": "2016-05-23T16:29:57Z", 
        "VersionId": "v3", 
        "Document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17", 
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface", 
                    "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones", 
                    "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways", 
                    "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups", 
                    "ec2:DescribeSubnets", 
                    "ec2:DescribeVpcs", 
                    "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface", 
                    "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute"
                ], 
                "Resource": "arn:aws:service:region:account:resourcetype/id", 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
            {
                "Sid": "",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "IsDefaultVersion": true
    }
}
```

As can be seen above, I have added this part

```
            "Sid": "Stmt2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
```

to my Trust policy above.

**The Problem**

Despite all these settings, I am getting the following error when I run my replication:

`Test connection failed for endpoint 'ep-target-redshift' and replication config 'rep-mysql-to-redshift'.'`

Also don't see any Cloudwatch logs, but I believe they are only generated when the replication runs.

Would appreciate some help on what I'm missing. Let me know if any clarification is required.

Answer (score 1):

The role and policy configuration for `dms-access-for-endpoint` role:

```
DMSAccessEndpointRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - dms.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDMSRedshiftS3Role
      Path: /
      RoleName: "dms-access-for-endpoint"
```

The role and policy configuration for `dms-cloudwatch-logs-role` role:

```
DMSCloudWatchLogRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      RoleName: dms-cloudwatch-logs-role
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "dms.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
```

Redshift Serverless endpoint URL is `xx-workgroup.123456781234.ca-central-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com` without port and DB name in the URL. This should be specified under server name. The port and DB name should also be specified in DMS endpoint configuration.

Comment: I successfully created the roles and policies that you suggested, also recreating the `dms-vpc-role` . 

Cloudwatch logs are being created, but the replication is still failing:
`Test connection failed for endpoint 'ep-target-redshift' and replication config 'rep-mysql-to-redshift'.'`

No intermediate S3 buckets are being created.

Cloudwatch logs only show this:

`{'replication_state':'testing_connection', 'message': 'Completed preparing resources for metadata collection. Testing connection to source and target endpoints to ensure proper configuration.'}`

Comment: Can you also specify what the `Path` parameter does, and why it's a slash.

Comment: I also added a Redshift managed VPC endpoint, although I had a VPC endpoint already, but that didn't help.

The Network ACL rules have an inbound of `All/0.0.0.0/0`, so that shouldn't be a problem.

The Route table settings are a bit confusing to figure out, maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: Would it be possible to post security group configuration for DMS replication instance, Redshift and RDS MySQL? Just the relevant information from inbound rules would be fine. Is your Redshift running on port 5439?

Comment: The SG for DMS Serverless has no Inbound rules. It has an Outbound rule of:
`All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0`

The SG for Redshift Serverless and RDS MySQL (the same Sg) has  Inbound rules of:
`Redshift TCP 5439 sg id of DMS security group`
`MYSQL/Aurora TCP 3306 sg id of DMS security group`

DMS and Redshift are Serverless.

Btw, I got this note from an AWS architect:

"I am afraid that Redshift Serverless is not yet supported by DMS Serverless , you can either use DMS with Redshift Serverless, or DMS serverless with Redshift provisioned"

Has anyone tried both Serverless before?

Answer (score 0):

I set up DMS provisioned and Redshift Provisioned, set up a DMS replication instance to test connections, but the connection between DMS and Redshift still failed.

Changing my Redshift cluster to be publicly accessible allowed connections, but that was not the solution I wanted.

Eventually, after some more digging, I found that the VPC endpoint for Redshift was missing an endpoint access policy, since DMS is version 3.5.1, Enhanced VPC routing is ON and Redshift is not publicly accessible, so it requires VPC endpoints.

Here's the endpoint and `PolicyDocument`, note that the `ServiceName` is region-specific:

```
DMSVPCEndpointRedshift:
Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint"
Properties:
  VpcEndpointType: "Interface"
  VpcId: !Ref DMSVPC
  ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.redshift'
  PolicyDocument: !Sub |
      {
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AccessSpecificAccount",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "${AWS::AccountId}"
                },
                "Action": "redshift:*",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
      }

  SubnetIds: 
  - !Ref EC2Subnet
  - !Ref EC2Subnet3
  PrivateDnsEnabled: true
  SecurityGroupIds: 
  - !Ref EC2SecurityGroup
```

Hope this is helpful.